# How to call DataFrameFunctions.createCassandraTable from Java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

How can I call this function from Java? Or do I need a wrapper in scala?

```
package com.datastax.spark.connector

class DataFrameFunctions(dataFrame: DataFrame) extends Serializable {
...    
  def createCassandraTable(
    keyspaceName: String,
    tableName: String,
    partitionKeyColumns: Option[Seq[String]] = None,
    clusteringKeyColumns: Option[Seq[String]] = None)(
  implicit
    connector: CassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(sparkContext.getConf)): Unit = {
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md ?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't help for creating a new table. And there is no version for 1.6x of the spark cassandra connector java API.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code :

```
DataFrameFunctions frameFunctions = new DataFrameFunctions(dfTemp2);
Seq<String> argumentsSeq1 = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("CategoryName")).seq();     
Option<Seq<String>> some1 = new Some<Seq<String>>(argumentsSeq1);       
Seq<String> argumentsSeq2 = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("DealType")).seq();         
Option<Seq<String>> some2 = new Some<Seq<String>>(argumentsSeq2);                                                               
frameFunctions.createCassandraTable("coupons", "IdealFeeds", some1, some2, connector);
```