# Create Cassandra Table from pyspark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Apache Spark 2.2.1 with Cassandra 3.11 and Datastax spark-cassandra-connector from python/pyspark.

And I would like to create Cassandra Table from dataset structure. So, I found a function `createCassandraTable` within DataSetFunction package in Java, but I am not able to find correspondence with pyspark package. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299108/how-to-call-dataframefunctions-createcassandratable-from-java) is a similar question in Java.

I am trying something like this:

```
dataset.createCassandraTable('examples', 'table_example', partitionKeyColumns = ['id'])
```

but `createCassandraTable` is not a method of dataset/dataframe.

I know that I could use raw CQL create table in spark, however I would like to do so dynamic and programmatically. Although, It is an alternative, maybe with a mapping between spark and cassandra types.

Any experience here or new ideas? Spark SQL alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue. 
But there is a way I think it can be possible. i.e using some driver lets say [cassandra-driver](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html) for python.

We can collect the require column fields from the data frame using available methods and can create the table programatically at run time.

After that, we may store the data using the following code,

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode('append').options(table=".options(table="kv", keyspace="test")kv", keyspace="test").save()
```

Comment: I recommend to rephrase to be more assertive but less bold. I.e. loose the "can be possible" and the bold attribute of everything else. Some more details might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for whoever that (like I was) is searching how to do this, you should know that there is now a way to do it with the [Datastax spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master) for python/pyspark.

```py
df.write.mode("overwrite").format(
    "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra"
).partitionBy("timestamp").saveAsTable(
    "myCatalog.myKeyspace.myTable"
)
```

You can find documentation describing how its done [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md#saving-a-dataframe-to-cassandra-1)

Answer (score 0):

A DataFrame can be saved to an existing Cassandra table by using the the **org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra** source and by specifying keyword arguments for *keyspace* and *table* and saving mode (append, overwrite, error or ignore etc.)

Example Saving to a Cassandra Table as a Pyspark DataFrame

```
df.write\
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
.mode('append')\
.options(table="kv", keyspace="test")\
.save()
```

The options and parameters are identical to the Scala Data Frames Api.

You can find more details in this [link](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md).

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Save data is not the question. I want to create table programmatically. It is ok for saving DataFrame contents not for table creation with similar structure than DataFrame schema. I think createCassandraTable method would be appropiate as in Scala or Java

Answer (score 0):

What about this? I know it is not the same what you are looking for, but it might be helpful.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'])
session.setKeyspace('myKeyspace')
session = cluster.connect()
session.execute("CREATE TABLE users (id int PRIMARY KEY, location address)")
...
cluster.shutdown()
```

You can even create KEYSPACE, set the factor replication and so on...
See the documentation here: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html

Comment: he is asking for function comparable to Scala's version, when Spark Connector infers all types, define table structure, etc. He knows about raw CQL way...

Comment: That is true. But someone might find it helpful anyway. I posted it, since there is no other way in pyspark, or is it?

Comment: No, as I know... Author is also knows that the raw CQL could be used - his motivation for a question is that the table structure should be somehow constructed automatically based on the types in the data frame

Comment: Maybe there will be some other way, how to do it, someday. Until then we have to use Scala or Java, haha  (actually we had to use Javaspark with other projects before because of pyspark limitations:))